# Numerical approximation of $\int_0^t\int_0^s\vert u-v\vert^{2H-2}((t+s)-(u+v)^{-d/2})$

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to have a numerical approximation of the following integral

$$\int_0^t\int_0^s\vert
 u-v\vert^{2H-2}\left((t+s)-(u+v)^{-d/2}\right)\, {\rm d}v\,{\rm d}u$$

with $t=2,],s=1,\,d=1,\,2H-2=-0.5$. Since the integrand explodes in many regions the method

```
NIntegrate[Abs[u - v - (1)]^-.75/((u + v ))^(1/2), {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}]**
```

fails, giving me the following message

> NIntegrate::zeroregion: Integration region {{0.5,1},{1.,0.999999999999999999999999999999975153439150570957241015732418974750}} cannot be further subdivided at the specified working precision. NIntegrate assumes zero integral there and on any further indivisible regions.

Can anybody tell me how I can get a good approximation to this type of integral?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful -- Also, do you get an error message? If so, please include it.

Comment: Getting to know your function helps:  `Plot3D[Abs[u - v - (1)]^-.75/((u + v))^(1/2), {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 20}}, PlotPoints -> 100]`.

Comment: NIntegrate[
 RealAbs[u - v - (1)]^(-3/4)/((u + v))^(1/2), {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 7] does the job, outputting 5.974551075.

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to match the general formula in the title or the text: `Abs[u - v]^(2 H - 2) ((t + s) - (u + v)^(-d/2)) /. {2 H - 2 -> -1/2, 
  t -> 2, s -> 1, d -> 1}` gets one $\frac{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{u+v}}}{\sqrt{\left| u-v\right| }}$ rather than your example $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u+v} \left| u-v-1\right| ^{0.75}}$.

Comment: @JimB: Then NIntegrate[
 RealAbs[u - v]^(2 H - 2) ((t + s) - (u + v)^(-d/2)) /. {2 H - 
     2 -> -1/2, t -> 2, s -> 1, d -> 1}, {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 7,Exclusions->{u==v}] outputs 7.378804176.

Comment: @user64494 I think your approach is the way to go (other than integrating separate regions).  My comment was about the OP's example not matching the general formula as there is no way to get a $u-v-1$ in any part of the general formula.

Comment: Did corey979 get the integrals reversed in the edit? I switched them to correspond to the limits in the code.

Comment: @MichaelE2.  No. Nothing reversed.  The thing I'm claiming as an inconsistency/error is that the OP has a $u-v-(1)$ term in the *Mathematica* code which cannot result from the general (LaTeX) equation.

Comment: @JimB Corey's edit had the $u$ integral going from $0$ to $s=1$ and the $v$ integral going from $0$ to $t=2$.  I thought it should be the other way and left a comment in case there is disagreement. (I picked it to match user64494's answer, since I thought it better to focus on one single integral.)  I agree with your comment that the code example does not match the TeX one, although it seems to have similar type singularities.

Answer (score 2):

Up to [the help on NIntegrate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html),

```
NIntegrate[ RealAbs[u - v]^(2 H - 2) ((t + s) - (u + v)^(-d/2)) /. {2 H - 
 2 -> -1/2, t -> 2, s -> 1, d -> 1}, {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 8, Exclusions ->{u==v}]
```

> 7.37875949086

Addition.

```
NIntegrate[ RealAbs[u - v]^(2 H - 2) ((t + s) - (u + v)^(-d/2)) /. 
{2 H - 2 -> -1/2, t -> 2, s -> 1, d -> 1}, {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1},
 WorkingPrecision -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 11,PrecisionGoal->11,Exclusions->{u==v}]
```

> 7.37875672406846B

Answer (score 2):

The IMT singularity handler works better when the singularity is parallel to an axis, so it's not surprising this appears to be a difficult integral.  The message is only a warning, but it's hard to know beforehand whether a warning implies an error.  Let's look at the OP's TeX'ed integral.

```
int = NIntegrate[
  Abs[u - v]^(2 H - 2) ((t + s) - (u + v)^(-d/2)) /.
   {H -> 3/4, t -> 2, s -> 1, d -> 1}, {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

> NIntegrate::zeroregion: Integration region...cannot be further subdivided at the specified working precision. NIntegrate assumes zero integral there and on any further indivisible regions.

```
(*  7.378756495073663`  *)
```

The reliability of the result depends on the assumption that there is a negligible contribution to the value of the integral in the integration region that cannot be divides because it is as small as possible at machine precision.  Since the integrand is approaching infinity in this region, it is not an obviously safe assumption.  However, it turns out that the result is accurate, with an error likely within the `PrecisionGoal` which is `6` digits by default.

To see that, evaluate the integral by other means or with higher precision and observe how stable the result is.  Here are a couple of different working precisions.  At the higher one, the default multidimensional rule is much slower than the cartesian product of Gauss-Kronrod. All these integrals evaluate without errors or warnings.

```
(int16 = NIntegrate[
    Abs[u - v]^(2 H - 2) ((t + s) - (u + v)^(-d/2)) /.
     {H -> 3/4, t -> 2, s -> 1, d -> 1}, {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.472966, 7.378756517051061}  *)

int32 = NIntegrate[
   Abs[u - v]^(2 H - 2) ((t + s) - (u + v)^(-d/2)) /.
    {H -> 3/4, t -> 2, s -> 1, d -> 1}, {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1},
   Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", WorkingPrecision -> 32] // timeIt
(*  {21.1778, 7.3787567240684493164029272938681}  *)
```

We can also get a fast, error-free evaluation at `MachinePrecision` using `"SingularityDepth"`:

```
(intSD = NIntegrate[
    Abs[u - v]^(2 H - 2) ((t + s) - (u + v)^(-d/2)) /.
     {H -> 3/4, t -> 2, s -> 1, d -> 1}, {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1},
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityDepth" -> 8}]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.085006, 7.378756757328596`}  *)
```

All of these results agree to seven or eight digits:

```
({int, intSD, int16} - int32)/int32
(*  {-3.10343*10^-8, 4.50755*10^-9, -2.8055863*10^-8}  *)
```

Finally, as implied in the opening sentence, things might be easier with a change of variables that aligns the singular like with an axis.  Let's let $w = u - v$, that is, $u = w+v$.  We also identify the singularity $w=0$ in the integration limits.  Then the integral becomes this, which is a little faster than the original integral and produces no warnings:

```
(intb = NIntegrate[
    Abs[w]^(2 H - 2) ((t + s) - ((w + v) + v)^(-d/2)) /.
     {H -> 3/4, t -> 2, s -> 1, d -> 1}, {v, 0, 1}, {w, -v, 0, 2 - v}]) // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.031386, 7.378756783881534`}  *)
```

Comment: For the other example in code, try `NIntegrate[
 Abs[w]^(-3/4)/(((w + v + 1) + v))^(1/2), {v, 0, 1}, {w, -v - 1, 0, 
  1 - v}, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]`
or
`NIntegrate[
 Abs[u - v - (1)]^(-3/4)/((u + v))^(1/2), {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]`.  The `3/4` power in the denominator is a slightly tougher singularity than the square root one:  It seems machine precision is not up to the task, AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica can do this analytically without too much difficult

```
integrand = Abs[u - v]^h ((t + s) - (u + v)^(-d/2));

Block[{d = 1, h = -(1/2), t = 2, s = 1}, 
 FullSimplify[Integrate[integrand, {u, 0, t}, {v, 0, s}]]]
(* 8 Sqrt[2] - (5 π)/6 - Log[2 + Sqrt[3]] *)

N[%, 20]
(* 7.3787567240684493164 *)
```

It can also cope with symbolic values for `s` and `t`

Comment: Can it cope with any other value of `h` between, say, `0` and `1`?